# how to break the <4gb ram barrier in win xp sp2?

Tags: windows-xp, memory, 32-bit, x86

I know that it can be done by taking a file from win 2k3 server and mod it to place it in xp, but thats all I know!

How can I do it?

Side note: PAE doesnt work in sp2 (it works but there is a hard-coded barrier from M$ that still doesnt allow you the >4gb usage)

Comment: Please don't bump.

Comment: Just update the system to Service Pack 3.  Service Pack 2 leaves the system vulerable to all sorts of attacks.

Comment: I am not here to discuss this. I posted the question, if you know then answer. Also sp3 has althis barrier too.
So all those who put a negative in my question, answer it instead of being cocky!

Comment: Now that style is going to get you a lot of answers.... (not). --- Someone who did not downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [Physical Address Extension - PAE Memory and Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487503.aspx)

Comment: I know about this, but it seems that even if you enable it in sp2, it doesnt work.

Comment: Physical Address Extension as mentioned by @alexus is what is required.  Period.  32-bit Windows is only capable of addressing up to 3.75 GB worth of RAM.  PAE is a 'hack' that Microsoft created to allow the CPU to address additional memory.